# Gitignore não funciona

Tags: git

Meu .gitignore continua exibindo as pasta e alguns arquivos.
Gostaria de ignorar todos de uma vez.
Deixei ele assim

## ignore

```
/*
*
/*/
*/*
*.*
.*
!.gitignore
```

## Not Ignore

```
#plugins/*
!plugins/Indicadores/
!plugins/Base/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só colocar o nome da pasta ou arquivo com extensão:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
```

O not ignore vai mostar normalmente, como o próprio nome diz.

Answer (score 2):

Se você já fez commit de arquivos/pastas que você não quer, botando eles no `.gitignore` não vai removê-los. Se for este o caso:

- Exclua os arquivos e pastas que você não quer do repositório.
- Faça commit das alterações.
- Altere seu `.gitignore` e faça commit.
- Agora seus arquivos serão ignorados.